# Keep getting random TLS handshake errors in Go

Tags: go

I keep getting this "random" TLS handshake error from time to time but I do not know specifically when this occurs, it just shows up all over the place in the logs.

```
2016/06/07 18:27:05 http: TLS handshake error from 169.229.3.91:53522: tls: oversized record received with length 34831
```

I got a Comodo PositiveSSL Certificate from namecheap.com. They sent me two files in email. One of the files they called the "Apache bundle"

```
Your Apache "bundle" file - mydomainname_com.ca-bundle
```

And the other one specific for my domain:

```
Your PositiveSSL Certificate - mydomainname_com.crt
```

I concatenated both of these files into an ssl-bundle.crt file. And use it with my private key which I generated on the server.

I use them like this:

```
router := httprouter.New()

// ...

certificate := "/srv/ssl-bundle.crt"
privateKey := "/srv/mydomainname.com-2016.01.01.key"
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServeTLS(":443", certificate, privateKey, router))
```

Why do I keep getting this TLS handshake error? What can I do to prevent this from happening? It is not really breaking the site or denying connections. It doesn't seem that way. It looks like things are working. But I still get this error or warning in my logs and I do not know what to do about it. Am I not correctly using the files I have gotten from the certificate issuer?

Let us assume that the Apache "bundle" file - mydomainname_com.ca-bundle, looked like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
(apache bundle block of string 1)
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
(apache bundle block of string 2)
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Basically two big blocks of generated string.

And that my PositiveSSL Certificate - mydomainname_com.crt looked like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
(positivessl block of string)
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

These were concatenated into a single ssl-bundle.crt file in this order:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
(positivessl block of string)
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
(apache bundle block of string 1)
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
(apache bundle block of string 2)
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

In the network tab in Chrome it says that it is valid https:

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: what clients at causing the errors?

Comment: Google Chrome browser on PC.

Comment: Or, maybe it is not me but crawlers? I don't know. How can I check the clients on the serverside?

Comment: It's either malicious or broken clients. You normally ignore them.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly. It is the issue when remote host does not support TLS connection even it was told to do. If you log those connection it will probably be crawlers with plain text HTTP request.

**UDP**

You error comes from here https://golang.org/src/crypto/tls/conn.go?s=17185:17253#L594 and it means client sends you bad Ciphertext (too big).  And it happens when you trying to Read from tls.Conn (or during handshake since it reads from connection itself). It returns you tls.RecordHeaderError as error, you can parse it's Msg field looking for this string.

Anyway it happens because client send malformed request, it could be damaged packet or client how dont respect your TLS config, or portscanner, or bad proxy, lots of reasons. But at that state connection is unrecoverable.

Check IP address you provided: http://169.229.3.91/, it says "This is a research scanning machine from the University of California at Berkeley. This machine regularly conducts scans of the entire Internet so you may have been scanned as part of an ongoing research project."

Comment: If there reason are crawlers, then how can I ignore errors and not log them if they are from crawlers? Or how can I know if an error is TLS handshake error?

Comment: There is a handshakeErr inside Conn struct, in https://golang.org/src/crypto/tls/conn.go. But I do not know how to reach it from another package and compare if the errors are the same.

Comment: Thanks for answer! I also get this error now: 2016/06/07 22:48:21 http2: server: error reading preface from client 46.249.229.7:49752: timeout waiting for client preface. Do you know what that might be?

Comment: i think its self explanatory =) Client connected using http2 and after initial connection he didnt sent preface frame in 10 seconds. After preface exchange connection is considered established. It is the first step after connection was passed over to your server from OS. https://github.com/bradfitz/http2/blob/master/server.go#L683